# SQL Query, two tables with a certain condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, Workers and Checkin.

Workers have an ID, name, role.
Check_in, has checkin_date (ddmmyyyy), checkin_id, and worker_id.

I want to find all workers that didn't check since Jan 2020.

The issue here is there are multiple checkins and I didn't know how to restrict it properly. I tried using a left join, where checkin_date < 00002020, but this doesn't work.

Comment: provide sample data, expect output, and what you have tried IN Proper format.

Comment: The format `ddmmyyyy` is not comparable. Change it to `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  select w.id,w.name,w.role 
  from workers as w
 where not exists
  (
     select 1 from Checkin as c where w.id=c.worker_id and c.has_ckeckin_date>'20200131'
  )
```

Based on your description you can try something like this